# Find names of people common to multiple attendee lists in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have five attendee lists for separate events.  I need to find anyone who has attended all five events.

I've used a work around by doing it two columns at a time to compare email addresses using `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D3,$N$3:$N$124,0)),"",C3)` but I would like to do it in one hit.

Or maybe the work around is less effort than creating the one hit solution!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. There are a couple pieces of information missing. 1) what version of Excel are you using? 2) can you give us an example of how your data is laid out? 3) Have you tried conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the five attendee lists are in simple ranges of cells (e.g., if they're all in their own columns), using a series of `COUNTIF` functions within an enclosing `AND` should work for all versions going back to Excel 2000:

[image: Excel screenshot]

For ease of use, the formula for cell B5 is reproduced below:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($E:$E,$A5)>0,COUNTIF($F:$F,$A5)>0,COUNTIF($G:$G,$A5)>0,COUNTIF($H:$H,$A5)>0,COUNTIF($I:$I,$A5)>0)
```

While this would be rather awkward to construct for a large or variable number of columns to search, it's not too bad for five datasets.  As long as your lists are in a format that's easy to reference by a formula like the above, it should do well for you.

(To note, there's probably a more elegant way to do this using the modern functions like `COUNTIFS`, if such is desired.)

Answer (score 0):

If you save the data as CSV, and import into access.

SELECT distinct "EmailAddress",count("EmailAddress") as x FROM "Addresses" group by "EmailAddress"

Then where ever the second column labeled **x** is 5 the email address occurs 5 times and therefore they were in all 5 classes.

Answer (score 0):

I ***think*** I have a better approach. I say *think* because this would be better if you have lots of data or have it spread over multiple worksheets (or even workbooks). It's also a good approach because the macro below can be used for a lot of other purposes when trying to find matching data (or, as the case may be, non-matching data).

In summary this macro allows you to find matching data between two ranges, either within the same worksheet or across worksheets. I have pasted the macro code at the bottom of this answer. I assume at this stage that you will know what to do with it. I also assume that you're using a version of Excel that runs in Windows.

**Summary of macro steps**

1. When you run the macro, it will ask you to select the range of cells
   containing the data you are looking for. For example, assuming in
   your first worksheet you have all the email addresses in Column C
   from C2 to C101, you would select that range.
2. Then the macro will ask you to select the range you wish to
   investigate. Just choose the range containing the email addresses
   for your second event.
3. The macro will then prompt you to specify a 'comment' for the macro
   to use to indicate it has found a matching item. You can specify
   anything here, such as "Found", "Yes", etc.
4. Finally the macro will ask you to enter a column letter. This is the
   column that the macro will place your 'comment' from the
   previous step into.

**For example**

Let's assume you have five identical worksheets in your workbook, each worksheet for each attendance list. Let's assume that Columns A to F are populated in each worksheet and that it is Column C that contains the email addresses. Let's also assume that you have 100 attendees, so that the email addresses appear from C2 to C101 in each worksheet.

Run the Macro.

At **Step 1** select the range C2:C101 in your first worksheet. At **Step 2** select the range C2:C101 in your *second* worksheet. At **Step 3** enter "Yes" as your comment. And for **Step 4** enter the letter G (just because it's the first empty column based in my example, but in your case it'll most likely be another column letter).

When the macro runs, Column G of your first worksheet will have the text "Yes" in any row where the email address was also found in the second attendee list.

Now, in your case, you would need to run the macro again. Follow the above steps, except that this time at Step 2 select the range C2:C101 in your third worksheet, and at Step 4 select the next column after the one you selected previously. In my scenario it'd now be column H.

When the macro runs, Column H of your first worksheet will have the text "Yes" in any row where the email address was also found in the third attendee list.

By now you'll start to see what's happening. By the time you repeat these steps to cover all your attendance lists, you will have four columns containing the text "Yes" where relevant. Now you can sort/filter your data so that only the rows containing "Yes" in all those columns are shown. These are the ones who have attended all events.

***Finally, before using any macro, make a backup of your Excel files so you have a clean copy!***

```
Sub FindMatchingData()
'This macro and Excel Add-In was designed by Monomeeth to allow users an easy
'way to find matching data between two ranges, either within the same worksheet or
'across worksheets within the same workbook.

Dim MySearchRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim findC As Variant

Set MyRange = Application.InputBox( _
Prompt:="Select the range of cells containing the data you are looking for:", Type:=8)

Set MySearchRange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Select the range you wish to investigate:", Type:=8)

Response = InputBox(Prompt:="Specify the comment you wish to appear to indicate the data was found:")

MyOutputColumn = Application.InputBox( _
Prompt:="Enter the alphabetical column letter(s) to specify the column you want the message to appear in.")

Set Sht = MyRange.Parent

  For Each c In MyRange
    If Not c Is Nothing Then

Set findC = MySearchRange.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not findC Is Nothing Then
           Sht.Range(MyOutputColumn & c.Row).Cells.Value = Response
        End If
    End If
  Next
Excel.Application.SendKeys Keys:="^{HOME}", Wait:=True
DoEvents
MsgBox "Investigation completed."

End Sub
```